# A Function $f$ such that $f' = f^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse-function

Example of a function that its derivative is the same as its inverse. That is

$$f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$

In [this video](https://youtu.be/rNUfiQgj6ZI) Michael Penn, shows a technique and presents a function with that property. The example is

$$f(x)=\sqrt[\varphi]{\dfrac{1}{\varphi}} \cdot x^{\varphi}$$
where $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

But his technique is based on an *intelligent guess*, is it possible to solve this problem in another way and find another function with this property?