# Solve Differential Equation $ f^{-1}(x)=f'(x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-function, golden-ratio

$$ f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$$ Where $f^{-1}:$ Inverse of f

I know for a fact there is a specific solution that is demonstrated on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNUfiQgj6ZI) and specifically:

$$ f(x) = x^{φ}\sqrt[φ]{\frac{1}{φ}} $$
Where $φ=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ration.

What I wish to do, is to find (if they exist) the rest of the solutions to the equation.
In case there is no other, I want to at least prove that there is no other solution.
For the record, I seek a conventional solution with a mathematical proof backing it, and not just through making "educated" guesses.

Comment: I posted  [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711598/a-function-f-such-that-f-f-1)  exactly 2 hours ago.

Comment: When I searched about it here, I got no results, however, thank you for reaching! I shall check it out the soonest!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function whose inverse is also its derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735695/function-whose-inverse-is-also-its-derivative)

Comment: Well, I won't lie. Those are just posts where the already given answer is validated. What I seek to do is to find other possible solutions without going through "educated guesses" or at least prove there are no other solutions.